# How to write the condition to check two cells values

Tags: excel, vba

AM new to VBA, i have two drop down lists in Cell C1 have two list ex:  (Project Name 1,Project Name 2) and another cell C2 with some list ex: (Emp 1 , Emp2 etc). I want a code to check the condition for Project Name 1 & Emp 1 then execute else go next  , on the same code i tried using if is not working. Can some one help me out.

```
For Each cel In Range("C2")
If cel.Value = "Emp1" And Range("C1").cel.Value = "Project Name 1" Then

ElseIF cel.Value = "Emp2" And Range("C1").cel.Value = "Project Name 1" Then
```

Comment: You dont need VBA to make 1 list conditional on another :) [Try this](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
If Cells(1,"C").value="Project Name 1" And Cells(2,"C").value="Emp1" Then
...
ElseIf Cells(1,"C").value="Project Name 2" And Cells(2,"C").value="Emp2" Then
...
End If
```

Comment: You will have to remove For loop. This will work without loop.